# Where can I ask something about pricing?

Tags: support, closed-questions

I just got [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/403811/how-much-can-get-from-my-cloud-app-until-i-reach-100-bill) down-voted and closed about the pricing on GAE/AWS/Asure. And I would like to know if there is a stackexchange site that is appropriate for it.

- My decision to ask on superuser and not on stackoverflow or programmers was made by checking what site has tags for GAE/AWS/Azure - and this turned out to be the only one.

Comment: Not really, because pricing means shopping recommendations and those are off-topic everywhere. So instead of focusing on the price, focus on what features you need and decide which matches your price level best

Comment: Will it be legitimate to ask how big the bandwidth will be? (You should write that as an answer - I would accept it)

Comment: IMO pricing isn't the only thing wrong with this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really, because pricing means shopping recommendations and those are off-topic everywhere.

So instead of focusing on the price, focus on what features you need and decide which matches your price level best.

As for estimating bandwidth, that's highly dependent on what your app is going to do, so talking hypothetically probably isn't going to make a lot of sense unless **you** know how much data you'll be using. Can't you cook up a local version and get a sense of what it requires?